# Parsing URLs with uploaded files from users

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Trying to parse uploaded URLs sent to a folder in this web form. The form initially only allowed for 1 upload but now they want more added and I can't figure out how to parse the URLs, the user may upload any number of forms, I've included what code I have for now.

```
protected void UploadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (fuSample.HasFile)
            {
                foreach (HttpPostedFile UploadButton in fuSample.PostedFiles)
                    try
                    {
                        string filename = Path.GetFileName(fuSample.FileName);
                        fuSample.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FileUploadFolder"]) + filename);
                        fileMessage.Text += String.Format("{0} <br />", UploadButton.FileName);
                        presentation.UploadPath += Server.MapPath(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FileUploadFolder"]) + filename;
                        UploadPathTextBox.Text = presentation.UploadPath;
                    }

                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                    fileMessage.Text = "Upload Status: The file(s) could not be uploaded. The following error occured: " + ex.Message;
                    }
```

Comment: Does this help? It looks like you should just use ````UploadButton.FileName```` to get the filename for each ````HttpPostedFile```` --  https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/99bb20/upload-multiple-files-using-fileupload-control-in-Asp-Net-4/

Comment: Does seem a little odd you are using UploadButton variable name when looping through each PostedFile, as that is the ID for the button click event.